# JQuery Mobile Apply custom theme to autodividers

Tags: jquery, css, listview, jquery-mobile

Is there any way to add attributes to programmatically created autodividers?

I'm generating the autodividers using the code below:

```
$("#classList").listview({
    autodividers:true,
    autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
        var hi = li.text().split(" ");
        return hi[0];
    }
}).listview("refresh").trigger('create');
```

And I want to set the data-divider-theme to b. I tried doing this after the dividers were created using the following commands in console:

```
$(".ui-li-divider").attr('data-divider-theme', 'b');
$("#classList").listview('refresh');
```

but the dividers didn't change in appearance. Is there any code I should add into the creation of the autodividers or after the creation of the autodividers to change this attribute?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **[dividerTheme](http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#option-dividerTheme)** option:

```
$("#classList").listview({
    autodividers:true,
    dividerTheme: "b",
    autodividersSelector: function ( li ) {
        var hi = li.text().split(" ");
        return hi[0];
    }
}).listview("refresh").trigger('create');
```

or just add the class `ui-bar-b` to the dividers

```
$(".ui-li-divider").removeClass("ui-bar-a").addClass("ui-bar-b");
```